# 230 volt tanning bed , rotary timer(separate panel box) has red wire capped off from 30 amp breaker

Tags: electrical

Just bought tanning bed used. Came with timer box that has red wire capped off. Black and white wires connect to timer transformer etc. It would run to 30 amp breaker in house panel. Is this normal?

Comment: It will depend if it just uses 230/240 or 120 and 240 volts.  There should be a label/plate on the bed with information including the maker and model number.  With this a search online should find a wiring diagram.  It might be made to use single wire 230v(Europe)  or two wire 240v(US).

Comment: Please [edit] to include brand & model number, as well as the picture requested above. Without that, you're probably not going to get much of an answer, but you may get a couple of wild guesses.